# Image aspect ratio inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: css

This'll probably be one of the easier questions, but I just cannot seem to find the answer.

I've got the following setup:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50%);
}

img.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

The image's width doesn't seem to change when shrinking the height of the window.

Here's a quick JSfiddle to demonstrate the issue. Adjusting the height of the window either skews or offsets the image, instead of adjusting the width accordingly.
https://jsfiddle.net/5p82ey8k/

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

width + translate is maybe not the best way.

block and margin auto is less tricky:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="" class="content">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5p82ey8k/2/

Comment: I guess I overthought the issue a bit. This should do the trick for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the image a well `<img/>` you could try this style.

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

This should preserve the ratio. However a better solution in my opinion is making the img a css `background-image`, and setting it's size to cover, like so:

```
.image {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: what about if image is part of the content and has a meaning ;) ? (background option )

Comment: Of course, that's why I posted both options. It's very important to keep img elements especially if they have alt attributes, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Thanks, but the image was meant to take the full height of the container, even if it's smaller, while keeping the correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement your picture as a background image instead of an img. and give the container this stylings.

```
background:url('imgurl') center center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

this way you could set the background-size property which allows you to let the picture always *covers* the container or *contains* it

[about background-size](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)

see working [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5p82ey8k/1/)

Comment: what about if image is part of the content and has a meaning ;) ?

Comment: you will see the image the same way only its implemented as bg and not wit h the image tag.. or what meaning you mean ;p?

Comment: nop, if i'm blind, i'll see nothing at all (nothing to read for my tools) , search engnes will see nothing either .... and then if image is there but empty alt attribute, again, nothing to find/read unless the image is loaded and that you are uman, looking at the screen ;)